# Box2d: crash on createBody in beginContact callback

Tags: java, libgdx, android, box2d, multithreading

I am getting this error on creating body in contactListener

```
com.patchnhack.gdx A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 4628 (GLThread 15500), pid 4583
```

I am creating a body in beginContact callback like this:

```
    ......
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        .....
        Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

        If( fixA.getUserData()== "ground" || fixB.getUserData()== "ground")
            createBody(0,0);
        ....
        ....
    }

// createbody method in screen class
    public void createBody(float x, float y, float radius) {
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        def.position.set(x ,y);
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        body = world.createBody(def);
        CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(radius);
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        fdef.restitution = 0.5f;
        fdef.shape = shape;
        fdef.density = 2;
        body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("chip");
    }
```

I know this is something due to async with render thread. Please tell me how can I resolve this or some better way to do this.

edit: I have even tried

```
Gdx.app.PostRunnble(new Runnable(){
..
})
```

But that works strangely and bodies keep populating and ultimately crashing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my silly mistake that ContactListener was invoked again and again because the body was responsible for making contact under gravity and creating infinite loop ;P

I enclosed the createBody() code inside `Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){ .... }`
And check if contact has already been made by a flag.

Comment: Can you share a little information about how you avoided this infinite loop, so it can help other developers who get themselves into the same situation?